# Illustrator clipping mask on blended lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, blending

I am newbie to Illustrator, just started out like a few weeks ago and was hoping someone could help me with this.

I wanted to do a clipping mask over few blends and its kinda not working out...

[image: This is how I want my artwork to look]
This is how I want my artwork to look like.
[image: And this is how it looks.]
And this is how it looks.
[image: When I add the background.]
When I add the background. Over here I am hiding the back part using a shape filled with white.
My question is how to make a clipping mask to hide the parts which are in the back, meaning the left hand part ?

Comment: And if I try Pathfinder > Minus Back
The entire left hand gets deleted.

Comment: I don't really understand this question or what you are trying to achieve. "over here I am hiding" is *really* ambiguous.. over where?

Comment: The left hand lines are intersecting the right because he is crossing his hands in an X shape so I want to hide the parts which are not supposed to be visible when seen from the front. Thanks for replying Scott.

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott, I really appreciate you trying to help, I have finally figured this out, Layer Clipping Masks sure are confusing.

Comment: @U.PraveenSuriyan You should post an answer describing your issue and how you fixed it then so others might benefit

Comment: Yes in a min getting it done.

Answer (score 1):

Normally selecting the top layer and the bottom layer and using Pathfinder>Minus Back would do the job, but that does not work in case of Blends.

So what I did here is grouped the left hand of the character, including blade and using the PEN Tool made a shape only including the parts that should be visible in my Artwork.
Then used the shape to mask the Left Hand of the character.

[image: Shape]

Comment: And voila, DONE.. phew..

Comment: If you solved your own problem and posted the solution as an answer, please consider making it the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark icon next to it. The more accepted answers we have, the more reliable this site is to newcomers. Thanks!